# JQUERY get the element after check if it has more than one 'td' parents

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm new in the world of jquery ,

i want to get then hide the elements with class (contracted) after check if it has more than one 'td' parents

PS : following on some problems in my code i don't want to use the if statements

the Example Code:

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <div class='contracted'>Something</div>
               
                <table>
                 <tbody>
                   <tr>
                     <td>
                          <div class='contracted'>Something</div>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
        
             </td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Sorry, what? Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.contracted').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents('td').length > 1;
}).hide();
```

Comment: this is it , tnks @Ryan Lynch ^^

Answer (score 3):

Elements with a class of `contracted` and more than one `td` parent can be selected and hidden as follows:

```
$('td td .contracted').hide();
```

Your code doesn't make it clear what you want to click to trigger this action, but you would bind a click event handler to the trigger element using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener on the objects you want:

```
$('td td .contracted.').on('click', functionName)
```

No need to listen to ALL .contracted elements... just the ones you want. :)